# Parse an XML Unit Test File with XMLLINT in Bash Script putting into Arrays for Success and Failures

Tags: android, bash, unit-testing, android-espresso, xmllint

I am running a script file on CircleCI where I do my UI unit tests and I need to parse the resulting XML from android and then find the specific tests that succeeded put them in a list and then take the failures and put them in another list.  I will then iterate through both lists and trigger API calls for each updating our Test Cases with the results.  One test equals one Test Case ticket.  In my bash script I have this so far:

```
totalTests=$(xmllint --xpath 'count(//testsuite/testcase)' $xml_file)
echo "Total tests = $totalTests"

# This is where I need help how to find the and grab the tag that has child tag of failure
failures=$(xmllint --xpath '//testsuite/testcase/????' $xml_file) 
echo "failures=$failures"

# This is where I need help how to find the and grab the tag that has no child tag of failure
successes1=$(xmllint --xpath '//testsuite/testcase/@name' $xml_file)
echo "successes1=$successes1"

IFS="$(printf '\nx')" && IFS="${IFS%x}";

for entry in $successes1
do
    number=`echo $entry | awk -F_ '{print $2}'`
    echo "CASE-$number"
done
...
# for loop for the failures ....
...
```

My test case out put looks like this

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<testsuite name="com.android.OnboardingBottomNavigation" tests="3" failures="1" errors="0" skipped="0" time="27.017" timestamp="2023-08-30T16:37:38" hostname="localhost">
  <properties>
    <property name="device" value="Pixel_4_API_33(AVD) - 13" />
    <property name="flavor" value="" />
    <property name="project" value=":app" />
  </properties>
  <testcase name="CASE_11447_Skip_Onboarding_Click_All_BottomNavs" classname="com.android.OnboardingBottomNavigation" time="5.483">
    <failure>java.lang.AssertionError: Expected value to be true.
at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:89)
at kotlin.test.junit.JUnitAsserter.fail(JUnitSupport.kt:56)
at kotlin.test.Asserter$DefaultImpls.assertTrue(Assertions.kt:648)
at kotlin.test.junit.JUnitAsserter.assertTrue(JUnitSupport.kt:30)
at kotlin.test.Asserter$DefaultImpls.assertTrue(Assertions.kt:658)
at kotlin.test.junit.JUnitAsserter.assertTrue(JUnitSupport.kt:30)
at kotlin.test.AssertionsKt__AssertionsKt.assertTrue(Assertions.kt:44)
at kotlin.test.AssertionsKt.assertTrue(Unknown Source:1)
at kotlin.test.AssertionsKt__AssertionsKt.assertTrue$default(Assertions.kt:42)
at kotlin.test.AssertionsKt.assertTrue$default(Unknown Source:1)
at com.android.OnboardingBottomNavigation.CASE_11447_Skip_Onboarding_Click_All_BottomNavs(OnboardingBottomNavigation.kt:39)</failure>
  </testcase>
  <testcase name="CASE_11445_Skip_Onboarding_Click_All_BottomNavs" classname="com.android.OnboardingBottomNavigation" time="15.353" />
  <testcase name="CASE_11446_Skip_Onboarding_Click_All_BottomNavs" classname="com.android.OnboardingBottomNavigation" time="2.513" />
</testsuite>
```

Comment: So I used this to parse the failures.  failures=$(xmllint --xpath '//testsuite/testcase[failure]/@name' $xml_file)

Comment: for success: successes=$(xmllint --xpath '//testsuite/testcase[not(failure)]/@name' $xml_file)

Comment: I find the following confusing: In the title of your question, you write `... into Arrays ...`, but you don't use even a single array in your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make a subquery in brackets which can evaluate to true:

```bash
xmllint --xpath '/testsuite/testcase[failure]'
```

```xml
<testcase name="CASE_11447_Skip_Onboarding_Click_All_BottomNavs" classname="com.android.OnboardingBottomNavigation" time="5.483">
    <failure>java.lang.AssertionError: Expected value to be true.
at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:89)
at kotlin.test.junit.JUnitAsserter.fail(JUnitSupport.kt:56)
at kotlin.test.Asserter$DefaultImpls.assertTrue(Assertions.kt:648)
at kotlin.test.junit.JUnitAsserter.assertTrue(JUnitSupport.kt:30)
at kotlin.test.Asserter$DefaultImpls.assertTrue(Assertions.kt:658)
at kotlin.test.junit.JUnitAsserter.assertTrue(JUnitSupport.kt:30)
at kotlin.test.AssertionsKt__AssertionsKt.assertTrue(Assertions.kt:44)
at kotlin.test.AssertionsKt.assertTrue(Unknown Source:1)
at kotlin.test.AssertionsKt__AssertionsKt.assertTrue$default(Assertions.kt:42)
at kotlin.test.AssertionsKt.assertTrue$default(Unknown Source:1)
at com.android.OnboardingBottomNavigation.CASE_11447_Skip_Onboarding_Click_All_BottomNavs(OnboardingBottomNavigation.kt:39)</failure>
  </testcase>
```

And `count` it:

```bash
xmllint --xpath 'count(/testsuite/testcase[failure])'
```

```
1
```

Or, you can negate it with `not`:

```bash
xmllint --xpath '/testsuite/testcase[not(failure)]'
```

```xml
<testcase name="CASE_11445_Skip_Onboarding_Click_All_BottomNavs" classname="com.android.OnboardingBottomNavigation" time="15.353"/>
<testcase name="CASE_11446_Skip_Onboarding_Click_All_BottomNavs" classname="com.android.OnboardingBottomNavigation" time="2.513"/>
```

And `count` it:

```bash
xmllint --xpath 'count(/testsuite/testcase[failure])'
```

```
2
```

Comment: Best explanation I have had from all my searches!  I am new to xmllint, not sure this is what I'll use but I needed some quick dirty way to do a POC.  Thanks I will mark answered once I test out.  THX

Comment: So I did this and its not printing in the for loop.  But using the not in the success loop it prints perfect.  exactly the same code except the  xmllint line.  failures=$(xmllint --xpath '//testsuite/testcase[failure]/@name' $xml_file)
echo "failures=$failures"

for entry in failures
do
    numberfails=`echo $entry | awk -F_ '{print $2}'`
    echo "CASE-$numberfails"
done

Comment: ahh nope it was the for loop I was missing the $ on the variable ... doh!  Thank you for the help